# read magento session expire time from configuration

Tags: magento, configuration

How can I read the value of session expire time from magento configuration :

System > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security > Session Lifetime (Seconds)

when I try to read all config of magento by this part of code that configuration not available to me.

```
$default_xml = Mage::getConfig()->loadModulesConfiguration('config.xml')
->getNode('default')
->asXML();
```

there a way to catch it by code ?

Answer (score 1):

If you take a look at:
`app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/system.xml`

It shows you the path you can use in the method below.

`Mage::getStoreConfig('admin/security/session_cookie_lifetime');`